# Subscribe in Angular2 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a question about `subscribe` in Angular2, please, help me...

I have two functions, first function return the value and the second function has to use it.

Here is my example

This is the first function, everything is ok and works works, and it returns `this.mapCenter`, this value I need later

```
   prevId () {
     let name, id, lat, lng;
     this.router.events
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .subscribe(e => {

        if (this.previousUrl !== undefined) {

          this.clickedMarker = this.previousUrl.substring(10);

          for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
            if(this.data[i].code === this.clickedMarker) {
              id = this.data[i].code;
              name = this.data[i].displayName;
              lat = parseFloat(this.data[i].lat);
              lng = parseFloat(this.data[i].lng);
              this.mapCenter = L.latLng([lat, lng]);
            }
          }
          // Open up the popup, when user comes back
          let myMarker = new L.Marker(this.mapCenter, {icon: mapUI.marker}).addTo(this.map);
          let mark = this.popupHtmlGenerate( name, id, this.mapCenter );
          myMarker.bindPopup(mark).openPopup();
        } else {
          console.log('not yet');
          this.mapCenter = L.latLng([48.145, 11.58]);
        }
        this.previousUrl = (e as NavigationEnd).url;
        return this.mapCenter;

      });
  }
```

Now I need to use the value this. mapCenter of this function as a parameter in second function.

```
this.mapInitialize(this.mapCenter);
```

The both functions are in the `ngOnInit`

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.prevId();

    this.mapInitialize(this.mapCenter);
  }
```

I tried something like `this.prevId().subscribe`, but I get error `subscribe doesn't exist on type void` ...

UPD: I can't assign second function in the first function. I need the second function later and if I assign it inside another function, everything brakes

Comment: Looks like `prevId()` isn't `return`ing the router.events subscription. Also, given the limited context, wouldn't it make sense to just call `mapInitialize` inside of the subscription? There doesn't seem to be a benefit to assigning `mapCenter` out only to reference it again afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

subscribe doesn't return values.  Its next interface is:

```
(value: any) => void
```

It only receives values.  This is how asynchronous event processing works.  As it stands, you need to move your mapInitialize function:

```
prevId () {
 let name, id, lat, lng;
 this.router.events
  .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .subscribe(e => {

    if (this.previousUrl !== undefined) {

      this.clickedMarker = this.previousUrl.substring(10);

      for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
        if(this.data[i].code === this.clickedMarker) {
          id = this.data[i].code;
          name = this.data[i].displayName;
          lat = parseFloat(this.data[i].lat);
          lng = parseFloat(this.data[i].lng);
          this.mapCenter = L.latLng([lat, lng]);
        }
      }
      // Open up the popup, when user comes back
      let myMarker = new L.Marker(this.mapCenter, {icon: mapUI.marker}).addTo(this.map);
      let mark = this.popupHtmlGenerate( name, id, this.mapCenter );
      myMarker.bindPopup(mark).openPopup();
    } else {
      console.log('not yet');
      this.mapCenter = L.latLng([48.145, 11.58]);
    }
    this.previousUrl = (e as NavigationEnd).url;
    this.mapInitialize(this.mapCenter);

  });
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.prevId();
}
```

This is the quickest way to make it work, but it could be substantially cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

you first method must be as a Observable method. like bellow:

```
public getByProvinceId(provinceId: number): Observable<CityModel[]> {

    const url = this.urlBase + `city/province/${provinceId}`;
    return this.http.get(url, this.options)
      .map((response: Response) => {
        const retVal = <CityModel[]>response.json();
        return retVal;
      });
  }
```

and (for example) in your second method use subscribe:

```
this.getByProvinceId(this.ProvinceId)
            .subscribe(result => {
                if (result.succeeded == true) {
                    this.regCities = result.returnValue;
                }
                else {
                    this.messageBox.ShowError(result.responseMessage);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems with the `prevId()` method is that it's got too many repsonsibilities, it

- calculates `this.mapCenter`
- invokes the popup
- sets the new value of `this.previousUrl`

The first thing you might do is extract the logic for mapCenter, like so

```js
getMapCenter() {
  let mapCenter = { name: '', id: '', lat: 48.145, lng: 11.58, latLng: null };
  if (this.previousUrl === undefined) {

    this.clickedMarker = this.previousUrl.substring(10);

    for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
      if(this.data[i].code === this.clickedMarker) {
        id = this.data[i].code;
        mapCenter.name = this.data[i].displayName;
        mapCenter.lat = parseFloat(this.data[i].lat);
        mapCenter.lng = parseFloat(this.data[i].lng);
      }
    }
  } else {
    console.log('not yet');
  }
  mapCenter.latLng = L.latLng([mapCenter.lat, mapCenter.lng]);
  return mapCenter
}
```

We can also extract the popup logic

```js
showPopup(mapCenter) {
  // Open up the popup, when user comes back
  let myMarker = new L.Marker(mapCenter.latLng, {icon: mapUI.marker}).addTo(this.map);
  let mark = this.popupHtmlGenerate( mapCenter.name, mapCenter.id, mapCenter.latLng );
  myMarker.bindPopup(mark).openPopup();
}
```

Now `prevId()` only does what it's label says

```js
prevId () {
  this.router.events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .subscribe(e => {
      this.previousUrl = (e as NavigationEnd).url;
    });
  }
```

Now we can see that `this.mapCenter` does not depend on the subscribed value of `router.events`, so it can run synchronously and get passed in to  `this.mapInitialize()`,

```
ngOnInit() {
  const mapCenter = this.getMapCenter();
  this.mapCenter = mapCenter.latLng;
  this.showPopup(mapCenter);
  this.prevId();
  this.mapInitialize(this.mapCenter);
}
```